# Deploying to azure with docker compose up

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose

I have been deploying my application to a remote host with the compose file below.

```
 
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  //volumes      
networks:
  pnet:   
services:
  // other services i.e. mysql etc.         
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: container-app
    restart: always 
    image: app-image
    ports:
      - 5000:5000 
    networks:
      - pnet
```

The Dockerfile from which the image is built

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I am trying to deploy to azure following the guide on the docker doc [Deploying Docker containers on Azure](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/)
The issue right now is I am getting this error

> containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InaccessibleImage" Message="The image 'app-image' in container group 'app_api' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.

This wasn't an issue deploying to current host after changing context to point to the remote host. What are the steps to make this work with deploying to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [docker documment](https://i.imgur.com/emCB2IH.png), you need to login to the container registry if your image is a private repository
after switching to the relevant docker context. In my case, I am using Azure container registry.

**Step1:** Switch to the correct docker context. which in my case is `myacicontext`

[image]

**Step 2:** Enable admin credential in ACR and login to the ACR as shown below.

[image]

[image]

```
docker login acrvjyhumbled.azurecr.io -u acrvjyhumbled -p dkjfdrgU5MvMM1T
```

Now, execute the `docker compose up` command. It will create container instance in Azure.

[image]

[image]